# How many reviews does "app store scraper" for Python scrape by default, and is there a fixed date range?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am confused about how many reviews the [app store scraper](https://pypi.org/project/app-store-scraper/) for Python scrapes by default and if there is any fixed date range ("past n months"). The documentation says that the maximum number of reviews fetched per request is 20, but I did not find a limit otherwise.

This tutorial states that if "how_many" is not provided, app store scraper defaults to scraping all:

https://python.plainenglish.io/scraping-app-store-reviews-with-python-90e4117ccdfb

Based on documentation and different tutorials, I have thus created the following script:

https://github.com/MonikaBarget/DigitalHistory/blob/master/JupyterNotebooks/Webscraping_ApplePodcasts.ipynb

This script sets the number of reviews to 7000, but even for top-rated podcasts that have been running for several years, reviews I can scrape do not seem to go back to the beginning and stay way below the 7000 thresholds. I was wondering if older reviews are inaccessible for other reasons.

As a sample, I have scraped reviews for two different podcasts.

1. The first one is "Black Girl Gone": https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/black-girl-gone-a-true-crime-podcast/id1556267741

The script with `how_many=7000` gave me 271 reviews, the oldest dated 2021-03-11 17:34:44.

2. The second podcast is "Crime Junkie": https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/crime-writers-on-true-crime-review/id949195280

The same script gave me 2000 reviews, the oldest dated 2022-07-17 16:13:36.

I would be surprised if Crime Junkie, which started in 2017, had no reviews on Apple before the summer of 2022. I am at a loss as to how those vast differences in scrapeable reviews occur and what I can do the scrape as many as possible.

Comment: did you find any solution! I am only getting 75! and the how_many parameter doesn't even work, I had to remove it from the request!

Comment: I figured out that you also need to loop through all the country codes to get all reviews possible as the app store is deployed nationally. So depending on the country code you use right now, the number of reviews you can capture will vary considerably. Also thanks to a colleague of mine, I have been able to create a functional script for my teaching. I will post a link as a response below.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the number of podcast reviews I could capture varied considerably has to do with how the app store is deployed. Each national instance comes with its own country code, so if you want to capture the full amount of available reviews, you need to loop through all country codes. Of course, you can also limit the selection to the US, the UK and other predominantly English-speaking countries.